# How to design a drop-down in button using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
 
//id define
var id = function (name) {            
             return{ 
                element : document.getElementById(name),
                   html : function (data) {
                          var ids = this.element;
                          if (data != undefined) {ids.innerHTML=data;}        
                          else{return ids.innerHTML;}},
                   val  : function (data) {
                          var ids = this.element;
                          if (data != undefined) {ids.value=data;}        
                          else{return ids.value;}},
                   hide : function () {this.element.style.display="none";},
                   show : function () {this.element.style.display="block";},
              clsremove : function (data) {this.element.classList.remove(data);},
                 clsadd : function (data) {this.element.classList.add(data);},
                    tex : function (data) { var latex = data.replace(/\^/g, "");
                                        var latex_form = latex.replace(/([a-z])(\d+)/g, 
                                        function myFunction(tot,c1,c2) {var tag=(c1 =='^'?'sup':'sup');return c1+'<'+tag+'>'+c2+'</'+tag+'>';});
                                         this.element.innerHTML= latex_form;
                                       }
                   }
                  }
//class define
var cls = function (name) {  
                            
              return{ 
                element : document.getElementsByClassName(name),
                   html : function (data) {
                          var ids = this.element;
                          for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
                          if (data != undefined) {ids[i].innerHTML=data;}       
                          else{return ids[i].innerHTML;}}},
                    val : function (data) {
                          var ids = this.element;
                          for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
                          if (data != undefined) {ids[i].value=data;}       
                          else{return ids[i].value;}}},
                   hide : function () { var ids = this.element;for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {ids[i].style.display="none";}},
                   show : function () {var ids = this.element;for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {ids[i].style.display="block";}},
                    tex : function (data) { var latex = data.replace(/\^/g, "");
                                        var latex_form = latex.replace(/([a-z])(\d+)/g, 
                                        function myFunction(tot,c1,c2) {var tag=(c1 =='^'?'sup':'sup');return c1+'<'+tag+'>'+c2+'</'+tag+'>';});
                                         this.element.innerHTML= latex_form;
                                       }
                   
                   }
                 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jfile/myquery.js"></script>

<script src="steps.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="text" value="20x+5k-10p-y=0">
<button onclick="checkFruit()">Check Fruit</button>
<p id="equ1"></p>
<p id="equ2"></p>
<p id="equ3"></p>
<p id="equ4"></p>
<p id="equ5"></p>
<p id="equ1p"></p>
<p id="equ2p"></p>
<p id="equ3p"></p>
<p id="equ4p"></p>
<p id="equ5p"></p>
<p id="xoneans1"></p>
<p id="xoneans2"></p>
<p id="xoneans3"></p>
<p id="xoneans4"></p>
<p id="xoneans5"></p>
<p id="xoneans6"></p>
<p id="xoneans7"></p>
<p id="xoneans8"></p>
<p id="xoneans9"></p>
<p id="xoneans10"></p>

<script>
function checkFruit() {
var reg =/([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-zA-Z])\b/g;
 
 var equation = id("myInput").val();
 var spli= reg.exec(equation);
 alert(spli);
  var text;
  var y= document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  switch(y) {
    case "20x+5k-10p-y=0":
   ans = "First add both side for -20";
   ans1= "Both side added by 10p";
   ans2= "Next both side added by y";
   ans3= "Divide by both side 5";
   ans4= "Solution for k value";
   
        document.getElementById("equ1").innerHTML = ans;
        document.getElementById("equ2").innerHTML = ans1;
        document.getElementById("equ3").innerHTML = ans2;
        document.getElementById("equ4").innerHTML = ans3;
        document.getElementById("equ5").innerHTML = ans4;
 break;
    case "20x+5k-10p-y=0p":
   ans5p = "First add both side for -20";
   ans6p= "Both side added by -5k";
   ans7p= "Next both side added by y";
   ans8p= "Divide by both side -10";
   ans9p= "Solution for p value";
   
        document.getElementById("equ1p").innerHTML = ans5p;
        document.getElementById("equ2p").innerHTML = ans6p;
        document.getElementById("equ3p").innerHTML = ans7p;
        document.getElementById("equ4p").innerHTML = ans8p;
        document.getElementById("equ5p").innerHTML = ans9p;
 break;
  case "20x+5k-10p-y=0x":
   xone1 = "First add both side for -5";
   xtwo2= "Both side added by 10p";
   xthr3= "Next both side added by y";
   xfour4= "Divide by both side 20";
   xfive5= "Solution for x value";
   
        document.getElementById("xoneans1").innerHTML = xone1;
        document.getElementById("xoneans2").innerHTML = xtwo2;
        document.getElementById("xoneans3").innerHTML = xthr3;
        document.getElementById("xoneans4").innerHTML = xfour4;
        document.getElementById("xoneans5").innerHTML = xfive5;
 break;
 case "20x+5k-10p-y=0y":
   xone6 = "First add both side for -20";
   xtwo7= "Both side added by -5k";
   xthr8= "Next both side added by 10p";
   xfour9= "Divide by both side -1";
   xfive10= "Solution for y value";
   
        document.getElementById("xoneans6").innerHTML = xone6;
        document.getElementById("xoneans7").innerHTML = xtwo7;
        document.getElementById("xoneans8").innerHTML = xthr8;
        document.getElementById("xoneans9").innerHTML = xfour9;
        document.getElementById("xoneans10").innerHTML = xfive10;
 break;

   


    // add the default keyword here
  }

}
</script>
<p id="super"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code in the linear equation steps. How can I allow the user to open the drop-down list, and select a single letter, for which my code will then show the corresponding algorithm steps?

For example, I would like to display the menu

```
[x
 y 
 z
 p]
```

from that button, the user selects **x**, and my code should display the steps listed in the **switch** case for **x**.

Comment: please any one can help this answer how to drop down button using to select the particular value and link the selected value to show the switchcase description

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is your time to start to form sentences...

Comment: Improved grammar; tightened wording.